# C++ .exe has stopped working - error in code

Tags: c++11, stack, queue, palindrome

I wrote a small program in c++, and it doesn't have any error on compile time but when I run the program, I'm facing with an error.
Following is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#include <sstream>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>

 #include "QueType.h"
 #include "StackType.h"
 #include "tools.hpp"

 #include <locale>

 #include <list>

 using namespace std;



 bool isPalindrome(const string& stringToCheck)
 {
 string line2;
 bool pal;
 string wrdF;
 stack<char> word1;
 queue<char> word2;

 char x,y;

 line2=stringToCheck;

// make lowercase
for (size_t j=0; j< line2.length(); ++j)
{
line2[j] = tolower(line2[j]);
}

std::locale loc;
std::string str = line2 ;
std::string::size_type al=0;

wrdF = "";
std::string::size_type al2 = 0;
while ( (al<str.length())  ) {

  if (std::isalnum(str[al])) {
      wrdF += str[al];

      al2++;
  }

  ++al;
 }

ItemType* items = new ItemType[al2]; 
strcpy(items,wrdF.c_str());

int oo=(int)al2;
for (int q=0;q<oo ;q++)
{
if (items[q] != ' ') {
    word1.push(items[q]);
    word2.push(items[q]);
 }
}
pal = true;
while (!word1.empty() && !word2.empty())
{
    x=word1.top();
    y=word2.front();
    if (x != y)
    {
        cout << "No palindrome" << endl;
        pal=false;

        break;
    }
    else
    {
        word1.pop();
        word2.pop();
    }

}

if (pal == true)
    cout << " palindrome" << endl;

return(pal);

}


 int main()
  {

 int row=0;
 string line;
 bool pali;
 ifstream myfile ("palindrome-testfile.txt");

ofstream palin("palindromes.log");
ofstream nopalin("nopalindromes.log");

if (myfile.is_open())
{

 while ( getline (myfile,line) )
 {

 //      cout << line << '\n';
  ++row;
 //      cout<<row<<". ";


 pali= isPalindrome(line);


 if (pali)
 {
    palin << line << endl;
 }
 else
 {
    nopalin << line << endl;
 }
 }

 myfile.close();
 }

 else cout << "Unable to open file";

 return 0;
 }
```

Please help me to resolve it. Thanks in advance.

[Capture of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxEDT.png)

Comment: please upload the image properly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28496851/how-to-upload-pictures-to-stackoverflow-for-posting

Comment: What's `ItemType`? I assume it's a typedef for `char`, in which case you have a problem here: `ItemType* items = new ItemType[al2]; strcpy(items,wrdF.c_str());` There's a buffer overrun, since you haven't allocated space for terminating NUL. In any case, it's not clear why you suddenly decided to use a heap-allocated buffer here, when you happily use `std::string` everywhere else to manage a sequence of `char`s. Note also that you are leaking `items`.

Comment: What's in `palindrome-testfile.txt`, and in particular on line 5 of it? Are there any non-Latin characters? If so, try `line2[j] = tolower((unsigned char)(line2[j]));` and `if (std::isalnum((unsigned char)(str[al])))`

Answer (score 0):

As Igor Tandetnik pointed out the problem is with the ItemType pointer. Which also leaks memory.

I wrote a similar code that checks if a word is palindrome. The [cppreference example for std::equal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal) is a is_palindrome function.

I am not sure about why you need the step for `std::isalnum`. That one will return true for numbers too. `std::isalpha` will return true only if they are are letters, [see cppreference doc for isalpha](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha)

Let me know if you need any clarifications.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

bool isPalindrome(const std::string& str) {
    return std::equal(str.begin(), str.begin() + str.size() / 2, str.rbegin());
}

int main() {
    std::ifstream myfile("palindrome-testfile.txt");

    if(!myfile.is_open()) {
        std::cerr<< "Could not open file" << std::endl;
    } else {

        std::string word;
        //operator >> will read words until you reach eof()
        myfile >> word;

        while(!myfile.eof()){
            auto str = word;
            //here I delete anything that is not alnum
            str.erase(std::find_if(str.begin(), str.end(),
                    [](unsigned char c) { return !std::isalnum(c); }));

            //Making all characters of the string lower case
            std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(),
                    [](unsigned char c) { return std::tolower(c); });

            if(isPalindrome(str)) {
                std::cout << "[" << str <<"] is palindrome" << std::endl;
            } else {
                std::cout << "[" << str <<"] is not palindrome" << std::endl;
            }
            myfile >> word;
        }
        myfile.close();
    }

    return 0;
}
```